# Trying to post photo directly to the news feed

Tags: facebook, photo

I am able to post photos from my android app to my Facebook wall and it is being placed in an application spesific album.
For my friends to be able to see this post I have to share it from inside FB by clicking share on the photo post.

What I want is to be able to post the photo directly to the news feed and along with the message and name parameter as well.

I am using me/photos but shouldn't I be using me/feed? I am using the putbytearray methode for the picture.

This is discussed up and down on different forums but I haven't found and good solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing can be accomplished with Facebook actions. However, fb requires that the photo is user generated. You will have to apply for approval from fb to do this.

Please read this:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/usergeneratedphotos

Comment: Hi Gil. Thank you for the info. This is the way to go. I gave it at try tonight and I`m eating on the approval. I even made a action publish to my wall as was expected before sending the approval request to Facebook. I will wait for the reply. May I contact you again if any problems occur?

Comment: if you comment here i'll receive a notification. good luck :)

Comment: While waiting for the approval I have breen reading something about the need for a public available webpage for processing the postings my users will do. Is this right?